# moveit_ros_control_interface/Ros2ControlManager crashed when used use_sim_time

Tags: gazebo, ros2, moveit, ros-humble, ignition-fortress

My goal is to set the movement to several working groups in Ignition Gazebo.
The movement is successful, but to simulate the gazebo, you need to use use_sim_time, but when using it in the following way.

```
run_move_group_node = Node(
        package="moveit_ros_move_group",
        executable="move_group",
        output="both",
        parameters=[
            moveit_config.to_dict(),
            {"use_sim_time": True},
        ],
    )
```

an error occurs.

```
[move_group-3] [ERROR] [1693428677.148925896] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints:
```

This happens only with the moveit controller manager(which is specified in the file "moveit_controllers.yaml"): moveit_ros_control_interface/Ros2ControlManager,
with moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager there are no such problems, but then you can only plan movement with one working group.